# Error when using remainder operation in z3py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, z3, z3py

Doing a remainder operation gives an error in z3py code

Following is my code

```
    x = Real("x")
    solve( x%2 == 3 )
```

The Code gives the following Error :

```
    z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Z3 integer expression expected
```

whereas when I am doing division operation it is working perfectly

```
    solve( x/2 == 3 )
```

(It gives an answer of 6)

Is remainder operation not supported in z3?
If it is how can achieve it?

Comment: Does the error happen on the `solve()` line, or the `x = Real()` line?

Comment: solve(). The error is happening when I call solve(...)

Comment: Is it possible for _any_ number to have `x % 2 == 3`?  If you're dividing by two, the largest possible remainder would be 1 (or 1.999), would it not?

Comment: That's what. Technically z3 should output 'unsat' as that equation is not satisfiable for any real value for x. Also this '%' operator is not working anywhere however it is used, whether a satisfiable soln exists or not.

Comment: _Also this '%' operator is not working anywhere_ Modulo operations typically have many solutions, i.e. `x % 2 == 1` is true for any odd number. What is `solve()` supposed to do if there are many possible solutions?

Comment: According to z3 manual if there are many satisfying assignments, it gives any one of them.

Comment: _According to z3 manual_ Have you tried one of the modulo examples in the manual, and does it behave as advertised?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the `%` operator returns a floating-point value, not an integer, if either of the operands is a floating-point value?  Although division works the same way, so I would have expected the other operation to have the same issue.

Comment: There is no modulo example in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulus for a real-value doesn't make sense; as real-valued division is precise.

It does make sense for integers. Is that what you intended? (Note your definition of `x` being `Real`.)